# GCC/ELF - from where comes my symbol?

Tags: linux, gcc, solaris, elf, ld

There is an executable that is dynamically linked to number of shared objects. How can I determine, to which of them some symbol (imported into executable) belongs ?

If there are more than one possibility, could I silmulate ld and see from where it is being taken ?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290799/how-can-i-find-out-which-library-is-home-to-a-given-object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [nm(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?nm), [objdump(1)](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/objdump.1.html) and [elfdump(1)](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/elfdump.1.html).

Answer (score 5):

As well as the ones Charlie mentioned, "[ldd](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ldd)" might do some of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you can relink the executable, the simplest way to find out where references and definitions come from is using `ld` `-y` flag. For example:

```
$ cat t.c
int main() { printf("Hello\n"); return 0; } 

$ gcc t.c -Wl,-yprintf 
/lib/libc.so.6: definition of printf
```

If you can not relink the executable, then run `ldd` on it, and then run `'nm -D'` on all the libraries listed in order, and `grep` for the symbol you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

```
$LD_DEBUG=bindings my_program
```

That would print all the symbol bindings on the console.